# Why cannot Wubi install Ubuntu as a primary install?

Tags: 12.04, wubi

Why does Wubi only install inside Windows Vista but not as a primary OS?

This is the first time I have had this issue as I have reinstalled or changed a HDD over the past couple of years. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1545.

Comment: Wubi is made so people can install Ubuntu like any other windows program. Is the problem the boot order or not putting the install on a separate partition?  There is still install from CD or usb

Comment: "Why does Wubi only install inside Windows Vista but not as a primary OS?" Because WUBI is not an OS but a tool to host an OS inside Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Wubi is an alternative Ubuntu installer through Windows. This is wubi, this is what it do. Install Ubuntu inside Windows (not alongside). Actually this is not even a regular installation. Ubuntu is hosted under Windows NTFS filesystem.

[Ubuntu Wubi Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) and [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for more info.

If you want to change the boot-order, then you should use **carefully** a Windows tool → 
[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

I strongly suggest to install Ubuntu alongside Windows = regular dual-boot.